# How to get a href value of current id

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to put my form id value in `a href` tab but it is not reflecting any value .

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var uid = data[i].uid;
                var firstname = data[i].firstname;
                var lastname = data[i].lastname;
                var email = data[i].email;
                var username = data[i].username;
                var password = data[i].password;

                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + uid + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + firstname + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + lastname + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + email + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + username + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + password + "</td>";
                html +="<td> <a href='edit.php '><button class='button' >Edit</button></td>";
                 html +="<td> <button class='button'>Delete</button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
```

How do I put my uid value in `a href` tag is this possible?

Comment: You mean on this line? `html +="<td> <a href='edit.php '><button class='button' >Edit</button></td>";`

Comment: What about `html +="<td> <a href='edit.php' + uid + '><button class='button' >Edit</button></td>";` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be resolved with little search on internet and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see the problem, but...

```
html +="<td> <a href='edit.php?uid=" + uid + "'><button class='button' >Edit</button></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use String concatenation:

```
html +="<td> <a href='edit.php?uid=" + uid + "'><button class='button' >Edit</button></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a tag data-uid = uid like-

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var uid = data[i].uid;
                var firstname = data[i].firstname;
                var lastname = data[i].lastname;
                var email = data[i].email;
                var username = data[i].username;
                var password = data[i].password;

                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + uid + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + firstname + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + lastname + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + email + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + username + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + password + "</td>";
                html +="<td> <a data-uid=uid href='edit.php '><button class='button' >Edit</button></td>";
                 html +="<td> <button class='button'>Delete</button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
```